# Is AutoIt "Managed Code"?

Tags: reflection, assemblies, autoit

An extension of my previous thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634531/c-wrapping-an-application-within-another-application).

I'm launching embedded resource applications via Reflection and I'm unsure whether I can use AutoIt (`.au3`) files or not. People say it needs to be "Managed Code". I'm not completely sure what that means nor do I know if AutoIt has that characteristic.

Comment: Is this a .NET question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed code is that which runs under the .NET CLR. AutoIt is not managed code.

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt is an interpreted language, so even if you embed a script inside another, it will be visible to anyone if you don't "obfuscate" the code somehow (like xor encryption for instance)

Answer (score 0):

See [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code) of managed code.

I doubt that AutoIt is managed code.  I was under the impression that it was simply run through an interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking whether AutoIT scripts are .Net assemblies.

I'm pretty sure they aren't.